# Can Memory leaks cause getaddrinfo EMFILE

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

I'm having some trouble with my NodeJS API.

Sometimes, it returns, `ConnectionError: getaddrinfo EMFILE` and is all is fuc** after this.

So, I've started to investigate. I found it would be caused by the "to many files descriptors open". We can apparently increase the number of open files that are authorized but it would not definitely fix the problem.

I found in [this article](https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/), that we can increase the file descriptors settings and the ulimit. But what is the difference?

Then, to try to isolate my problem, I've run the `lsof -i -n -P | grep nodejs` command. Indeed, the number of connections established is increasing, so I imagine I have somewhere in my code some connections that are not closed.

I have some `fs.readFileSync` and `fs.readDirSync` etc… but I have not set the `autoClose:true`. Did you think it would be that?

Do you have any ideas or advice?

PS : the App run on a Ubuntu machine

---

**EDIT , 16-02-2016**

I have ran this command on my production machine `lsof -i -n -P | grep nodejs`

What I see is something like this:

```
...
nodejs    27596   root  631u  IPv4 109781565      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45268->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  632u  IPv4 109782317      0t0  TCP 172.31.58.93:4242->172.31.55.229:61616 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  633u  IPv4 109779882      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45174->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  634u  IPv4 109779884      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45175->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  635u  IPv4 109781569      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45269->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  636u  IPv4 109781571      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45270->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  637u  IPv4 109782319      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45293->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  642u  IPv4 109781790      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45283->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  643u  IPv4 109781794      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45284->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  644u  IPv4 109781796      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45285->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  645u  IPv4 109781798      0t0  TCP 172.31.58.93:4242->172.31.55.229:61602 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  646u  IPv4 109781800      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45286->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  647u  IPv4 109781802      0t0  TCP 172.31.58.93:4242->172.31.0.198:1527 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  648u  IPv4 109781804      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45287->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
nodejs    27596   root  649u  IPv4 109781806      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45288->127.0.0.1:7272 (ESTABLISHED)
```

But I don't know what it means, do you have any ideas about this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I thought I found out what is going on!

I use Redis & Redis session npm modules for my cart storage, but when I created, updated, I created a connection to Redis, each time, before using it.

```
var session = new Sessions({ port : conf.redisPort, host : conf.redisHost});

session.get({
    app :    rsapp,
    token :  this.sessionToken },
    function(err, resp) {
        // here some workin'
    })
```

Now I just created the connection when my app starts and store this as a singleton and use whenever I want.

```
// At the start of the App
    var NS = {
        sessions        : new RedisSessions({port: config.redisPort, host: config.redisHost}),
    };

// Later somewhere in the app        
    NS.session.get({
        app :    rsapp,
        token :  this.sessionToken },
        function(err, resp) {
            // here some workin'
        })
```

It was pretty obvious but now I found it… If it can help someone, I'll mark this one as solved.